# Truffle Contract Abstraction Contract.at() not returning logs when methods are called

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, vyper

In my test file I have this set up:

```
let acc = await Account.deployed()
```

Then when I call a method, I can get the logs in the receipt:

```
let deposit = await acc.deposit()
console.log(deposit.receipt.logs)
```

But when I do this:

```
let acc = await Account.at(sellerAcc)
let deposit = await acc.deposit()
console.log(deposit.receipt.logs)
```

There are no logs on the receipt and the console returns undefined!
Not sure how this is functioning but I know the difference is with Contract.deployed() and Contract.at(), so what's going on?

How do I get sellerAcc in  above:

```
let fac = await AccountFactory.deployed()
let seller = accounts[0]
let sellerAcc = await fac.getAccount(seller)

let acc = await Account.at(sellerAcc)
```

getAccount function from Factory contract

```
user_to_account: map(address, address)

@public
@constant
def getAccount(user: address) -> address:
    return self.user_to_account[user]
```

Comment: What is `address`?

Comment: BTW, `at` is not an `async` function, so you don't need to precede it with `await`.

Comment: @goodvibration address is the address of an Account contract

Comment: Well, apparently it's not. Can you please post your code for obtaining this value?

Comment: @goodvibration posted, thank you for helping me out

Comment: I only asked you to show how you obtain the value of `address`, not your entire code. And BTW, I can't see that piece of information even after you posted all that tons of code! Please post ALL the relevant information and ONLY the relevant information. Thank you.

Comment: @goodvibration fixed

Comment: I suggest that you print `acc.address` in your first test and `sellerAcc` in your second test, and observe that they are not the same.

Comment: @goodvibration that's what I want to fix, I want acc.address to be the same as sellerAcc so I can call sellerAcc methods. sellerAcc is a proxy account that will give authorization to another contract to deposit and withdraw ether from it, so I want the seller -> msg.sender of sellerAcc, so when I call sellerAcc.deposit({value: 1}) I am sending that tx from seller address

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue.

I have my AccountFactory contract that helps setup new Account contracts. AccountFactory takes one parameter for the **init**: TemplateAddress. This template address is a deployed instance of Account contract.

My problem: I was not passing in the correct TemplateAddress, I was passing in my accounts[0] address.

By passing in the correct template address, my code functioned properly.